# Extracting image from a flash Webcam

Tags: android, flash, webcam-capture

I am working in a personal project on Android and I would like to add images captured from Webcams into the app, e.g from here:

https://www.skylinewebcams.com/en/webcam/united-states/new-york/new-york/new-york-manhattan.html

My problem is the Webcams are in Flash and I want to show in the app just a picture.jpg or .png captured , so I am thinking:

```
1.- Getting a webCam screenshot using the webcam url (will called with a cronojob)
2.- Saving the screenshot in a database
3.- Showing the screenshot in the app
```

I am trying with tools like *www.screenshotlayer.com* or *www.whoapi.com* but the problems I have are:

- WebCam is not loaded when the script gets the screenshot, so in the screenshot is just exhibited the loader.
- The screenshot does not contain the image captured (like the image I am attaching getting from  screenshotlayer.com)

Any idea about how solve this?

[image: Webcam captured using screenshotlayer.com]

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem and have to switch to http://browshot.com The do support flash elements.